# Deploy Virtual Machine on Azure through Python

Tags: python, azure

I'd like to deploy VMs on Azure through Python. I followed this guideline. https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/resources/samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/ Step 1 - 5 are done.

I'm stuck at step 6.

```
6. Fill in and export these environment variables into your current shell.

   export AZURE_TENANT_ID={your tenant id}
   export AZURE_CLIENT_ID={your client id}
   export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET={your client secret}
```

I use a Windows machine and it's not clear what I need to do. It's gonna be a very simple thing, but I can't figure it out :-(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set environment variables in windows, instead of:

```
export AZURE_TENANT_ID={your tenant id}
```

use

```
set AZURE_TENANT_ID={your tenant id}
```